# Changing the undocumented "TypeError: Failed to fetch" response to a custom default response

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a question regarding the "Undocumented  TypeError: Failed to fetch" response inside the Swagger UI.

This is not a CORS issue, I am not interested in fixing this error.
Is there a way to present this response in some other way, can I create my own default placeholder response for this?
This error would happen when the server is down. I want to have default response for this like: Server is down.

I realize that there is a default option I can add to responses in yaml file, but this does not work if the server does not respond. Of course, there is no error code, there is just Status: (failed) (inside of the inspect Chrome network tab).

Can I somehow cover this response, make it my own?

If that is not possible, can I make any undocumented request default to some http response code, like 500 for example?

Comment: You may have better luck asking this in the Swagger UI repository at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues